# Change the javadoc font in intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Does anyone know how to change the Javadoc font type in Intellij Idea? I am very new to Intellij and I don't find the font very pleasing.

Comment: I don't think there's an option for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go to

> Setting > Editor > Colors & Fonts > Java

Here you can set fonts and colors. You can click on the specific part in the lower part and set the font and colors for this:

[image]

Comment: Well I have already created a new scheme under Settings > Editor > Color & Fonts > Font, and changed the font to consolas. But when I open the Javadoc (pressing Ctrl +Q on a method) I don't think the font is Consolas.

Answer (score 0):

It seems impossible for now to change only the font used for the rendered javadoc, but it is possible.

The font of the javadoc is the same as the font of the IDE, which you can easily change:

- open the IDE settings (Ctrl+Alt+S),
- go to *Appearance & Behavior*,
- go to *Appearance*,
- check *Use custom font*, and choose a font (like Consolas or JetBrains Mono).

Your javadoc will use this custom font, but so will do all your IDE. Personally, it doesn't bother me, so it's the solution I went with.